# Visual Studio Failing to Create C++ Console Project

Tags: c++, windows-10, visual-studio-2015

I have a problem where Visual Studio will not create a new C++ Console Application project. I can input the project name and location, but when I hit the create button it simply closes the project creator window and reopens it without creating anything. It will do this with both types of the standard C++ Win32 project templates. Everything else works and will load without this error, but for whatever reason Visual Studio will not create Win32 C++ project types. I have previously been able to create such projects in the past; the problem I am encountering is recent.

My version of Windows 10 has recently been updated to the most recent version, but I do not think this will have effected the program. I have tried to run the repair tool included with Visual Studio and running it as an administrator, but nothing has helped. Can you please tell me why Visual Studio might be refusing to create Win32 Projects and how to fix it?

Comment: Try restarting the computer (not shutdown)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I completely uninstalled Visual Studio and it worked fine after that. Rebooting didn't help; the reinstall did the trick.